# build.sbt and application.conf are not reading environment variables set by .env

Tags: scala, docker, playframework, sbt

I'm attepmting to build a container of a Play Framework application. For this I'm using the sbt-native-packager plugin and using the command 'sbt clean docker:publishLocal'.
To simplify future pipelines and the dev environments, I enable the sbt-dotenv plugin to use a .env file where I can define my variables. The variables are being used in build.sbt and application.conf

build.sbt

```
name := sys.env.get("APP_NAME")
organization := sys.props.get("CLIENT_NAME")
version := sys.props.get("APP_VSN")
```

application.conf uses them as follows, to allow for defaults

```
default.username = username
default.username = ${?DB_USERNAME}
default.password = password
default.password = ${?DB_PASSWD}
```

When running sbt clean docker:publishLocal, I can see the plugin loading the variables but the configuration files can never find them and always fallback to defaults. Since my understanding of Docker is a bit limited, I thought that maybe I needed to pass the envVars to Docker as follows:

```
dockerEnvVars := Map("APP_NAME" -> sys.env.get("APP_NAME").....
```

But this is not working either, they are present in the final container but I need them in the building process so the configuration files can build the distributable with them.
I don't really know what else to try. I have tried different methods to get the envvars, trying different versions, updating my plugins and can't seem to find anything like this on the internet.

Comment: Which env vars you want to set during building? Because adding credentials to docker image is a bad security practice.

Answer (score 3):

sbt-dotenv sets environment variables at build time, while the Lightbend config library resolves them at runtime. If you want the variables in application.conf to be substituted at compile time, you can:

- write an sbt task that will load `application.conf`, resolve the variables and create a new config file containing the actual values
- customize the `mappings` task so that the original `application.conf` is not included in the final image and your new, generated config file is used instead

But frankly, this whole thing just smells like a bad idea. Why don't you just use the `--env` flag for `docker run` and set the environment variables there?

Comment: What I did was create a bash script that lets you set your env vars for testing, and then either run the project or build a container with sbt docker. This way I can set envVars in Gitlab CI and for testing.